# How to migrate from Nexus Repository to JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, nexus, migrate

I have two servers, one with Nexus Repository and one with JFrog Artifactory OSS.

I would like to migrate to JFrog Artifactory but because it is open source there is no tool to migrate. If it were the pro version I could migrate easily.

I need some idea how to migrate from Nexus Repository to JFrog Artifactory OSS.

Comment: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Migrating+from+Sonatype+Nexus+Repository+Manager+to+Artifactory Here is the Jfrog supported nexus to artifactory page.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I accomplished this task was to:

1. manually download the repos from Nexus. For nexus2 you can directly copy the repos from the filesystem. For nexus3 you will need to use the API. For nexus3 I used a script that I will put below.
2. Zip the repos into a folder
3. Upload the zipped file to artifactory with their import tool. Go to admin panel, artifactory, import, repositories.

You should be good to go from there more or less. I had to manually set some permissions and snapshot settings.

**WARNING! This script doesn't work 100% you may/will have to modify it. WARNING!**

```
sourceServer=
sourceRepo=
sourceUser=
sourcePassword=
logfile=$sourceRepo-backup.log
outputFile=$sourceRepo-artifacts.txt

# ======== GET DOWNLOAD URLs =========
url=$sourceServer"/service/rest/v1/assets?repository="$sourceRepo
contToken="initial"
while [ ! -z "$contToken" ]; do
    if [ "$contToken" != "initial" ]; then
        url=$sourceServer"/service/rest/v1/assets?continuationToken="$contToken"&repository="$sourceRepo
    fi
    echo Processing repository token: $contToken | tee -a $logfile
    response=`curl -ksSL -u "$sourceUser:$sourcePassword" -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' "$url"`
    readarray -t artifacts < <( jq  '[.items[].downloadUrl]' <<< "$response" )
    printf "%s\n" "${artifacts[@]}" > artifacts.temp
    sed 's/\"//g' artifacts.temp > artifacts1.temp
    sed 's/,//g' artifacts1.temp > artifacts.temp
    sed 's/[][]//g' artifacts.temp > artifacts1.temp
    cat artifacts1.temp >> $outputFile
#for filter in "${filters[@]}"; do
     #   cat artifacts.temp | grep "$filter" >> $outputFile
    #done
    #cat maven-public-artifacts.txt
    contToken=( $(echo $response | sed -n 's|.*"continuationToken" : "\([^"]*\)".*|\1|p') )
done


# ======== DOWNLOAD EVERYTHING =========
    echo Downloading artifacts...
    urls=($(cat $outputFile)) > /dev/null 2>&1
    for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
        path=${url#http://*:*/*/*/}
        dir=$sourceRepo"/"${path%/*}
        mkdir -p  $dir
        cd $dir
        pwd
        curl -vks -u "$sourceUser:$sourcePassword" -D response.header -X GET "$url" -O  >> /dev/null 2>&1
        responseCode=`cat response.header | sed -n '1p' | cut -d' ' -f2`
        if [ "$responseCode" == "200" ]; then
            echo Successfully downloaded artifact: $url
        else
            echo ERROR: Failed to download artifact: $url  with error code: $responseCode
        fi
        rm response.header > /dev/null 2>&1
        cd $curFolder
    done
```